# Executing a process in server after synchronization in Genexus Smart Devices

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

In an Android app developed in Genexus Ev3 U4, I need to execute a process in the server after the synchronization ends. The process is an external process in SQL server that uses the recently added records to generate a report.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure [`GxAfterEventReplicator`](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Error%20handling%20in%20Synchronization.Send%28%29%20operations,) (under folder `GxSynchronization`) is called after the replicator applied all the BC operations incoming from the device to the server database.

This procedure receives a variable `&EventResults` of type `GxSynchroEventResultSDT` which holds information about the BCs applied due to synchronization.

You may then modify this procedure to add a call to a SQL stored procedure by  issuing a [`sql`](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?SQL%20Command,) command.

Comment: Thanx a lot... I'll try this solution.